# Print some pages in C# don't want to show on browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a project in which I have to print some reports that I generate. I have 5 reports that I can display on html pages.

But, I just want to print all those reports without showing them to the user. I just want them to be printed directly from the back-end.

```
var getAll5Reports; // has all the reports
```

As an example, here is the html code as a report:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>ListResult</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have direct access to the printer on the server side or through some client-side control?  Otherwise you will have to present the user with a "print" dialog window and the content of the page beneath will contain the content.

Comment: no i don't have direct access to the print from server side

Comment: Got a idea let me try thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

The way you control what content does or does not get printed from a browser is to use the @media CSS selector (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp)

In your CSS you would have something like this:

```
@media print
{
    @page
    {
        size: 8.5in 11in;  /* width height */
    }

    .noprint
    {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Then using JQuery or whatever type of JavaScript support you have, you add the `noprint` class to the reports you don't want. (https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

```
$('#myreport').addClass('noprint');
```

At the same time you could use the @media print to change the way some things are formatted so that it looks good on paper.  You might want to check out more info on paged resources (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_paged_media.htm)

Of course, you don't have to add the "noprint" class via JavaScript.  You can do it in your markup, or as you generate your page.

Answer (score 0):

If your reports are rendered in HTML and you want to print them from the back end without the user seeing anything (i.e. no print dialogs or anything like that), I've had good success in the past using the MeadCo ScriptX component for this purpose.

http://scriptx.meadroid.com/

I've been able to use it in the past to print directly to a printer. What I found useful at the time is that it will print an html page directly to the printer from the server (e.g. you could retrieve your HTML using Server.Execute and then pass it to the component, along with printer routing information).

It's a commercial component so has paid-for licensing concerns, but did fit the bill for me in terms of printing an HTML page with no input at all from the user (i.e. no print dialog popups etc). There may well be competitor products, I'm unfamiliar with them though, worked with this some time ago.

(I don't work for, or have any affiliation with the vendors!)